# Should logic regarding an user's actions history be placed inside or outside the domain?

Tags: oop, architecture, uml, domain-driven-design, cqrs

Assuming this write model with 4 aggregates :

[image]

The application needs to block/ban any clients that have visited the store more than x number of times in x days interval .

Where should I put this logic? If it should be in the domain layer , should I make a ClientStoreVisitHistory entity just for this logic? Or should i put this logic outside the domain ?

Any help is much apreciated .

Comment: Why do clients visit store? What business problem does the whole application aims to solve?

Comment: @hippom The model is just an example to show where my problem is . There is no need to think about other behaviour ... my main problem is the behaviour/logic that needs to know about all the StoreVisits made by a client, and after that compare that history with store's limitations . Should this be in the domain or outside? Populating an aggregate with an entire history of visits seems unpropper. This can be solved with a simple query on the persisted historic data .

Comment: I supposed that the application provides some services other than just limiting visits. In this case, there are at least two domains, one is core-domain targeting the core business concerns, the other targets identity and access. Your model above should be placed in the second one. Now let us get back to your question: The logic is in the identity and access domain which serves as an infrastructure for the core-domain(thereby it is out of the core-domain).

Comment: Actually everything in the domain is tied to the client/store entities . I was thinking of doing it like this : StoreVisitLimitSpecification (1:1 with store) inside the store aggregate . StoreRecentVisitActivity Entity aggregation association to StoreVisitLimitSpecification . Inside the StoreVisitLimitSpecification check if the visit generates a block/ban : if the client that made a StoreVisit has allready been seen x times in the StoreRecentVisitActivity then block him . What do you think ? P.S. : StoreRecentVisitActivity would hold some ind of reference to visits in the x days limit period .

Comment: By "block", do you mean reject accessing (such as http access) or just a logic constraint?

Comment: By block/ban i mean just a simple behaviour , the StoreVisit is valid even if the client exceeds the limits. I just label him, the client, as baned/blocked for a store if he goes over the limit . But he still can make visits.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51156/discussion-between-hippoom-and-tudor-tudor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The restriction you are talking about clearly belongs to problem domain and should be modelled there. I would not create  any new classes for that and would rather put this logic in the constructor of the object StoreVisit. As it directly handles visits to Store and accepts two arguments (client and store) you don't add any new dependencies or new classes this way and have access to all needed info to assess the visit.

And a note... If you model classes of the problem domain, I suggest not modelling entities' id's (they are assumed and the model is clearer), to specify better the associations and to add some methods. The way you did it, it looks more like a DB design.

**UPDATE (after the comments)**

A separate „StoreVisitLimitSpecification“ entity makes sense if there is a need for more than a couple of attributes (currently clientVisitsLimit and daysIntervalForclientVisitsLimit). If you expect this entity to grow in the future it is reasonable to have it as a separate class. If you expect current version to be stable, it is also acceptable to have all in one class.

And regarding the following:

> StoreRecentVisitActivity Entity aggregation association to
>   StoreVisitLimitSpecification . Inside the StoreVisitLimitSpecification
>   check if the visit generates a block/ban : if the client that made a
>   StoreVisit has allready been seen x times in the
>   StoreRecentVisitActivity then block him .

- I don’t think this is a good idea. StoreRecentVisitActivity class is completelly redundant, as StoreVisit already holds the visit history. We want to keep our domain model simple and small
- I would definitely avoid checking for block/ban inside StoreVisitLimitSpecification. As its name suggests, this is a helper, specification class and should be totally passive, without any logic and only queried from the outside. Itself should therefore not be responsible for any kind of validation. As told, I would put this logic in the StoreVisit constructor or eventually (if very complex) in a separate helper class of StoreVisit. It could be fetched from there via Store class (as it belongs to the Store).

This would me my recommendation for the domain model:

[image: Domain class model]

And here is a sequence diagram showing the process of creating a new StoreVisit:

[image: New StoreVisit sequence]

I find it compact, simple and clear. StoreVisit holds all the data of Visit history and therefore can access it without additional classes of dependencies. Store holds the reference to LimitsSpec and gives it on request to StoreVisit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .Mentioning that the visit is valid even if the client goes over the limit. I just add him to a blacklist if he goes over the limit. Checking the visit history inside the StoreVisit it does not seem a good ideea , specially when i need to check the Store visit limitations. This logic should be in separate objects. Also regarding the ids, it's easyer to work with the persistance layer if there is a GUID or something to differentiate the objects (working with identifiers that spans across attributes overcomplicates the whole problem). P.S. : Read my comments above

Comment: (an UPDATE section added to answer text)

Comment: StoreVisit does not hold visit history :) . StoreVisit is just a visit, it helps to keep track of a visit :) . It's not a visit collection , it's just a visit . The visit collection could be inside the store aggregate or client aggregate. Also there might be tens of thousand  of visits , does one really need to call all the history from the persistance layer inside one aggregate , when this could be done by reading the persistance store? Also you could use specification for validation, check if the new visit is beetween the days interval of the store limit, depends how you view it.

Comment: We should here distinguish two different perspectives and correspondingly two different models: conceptual domain model and physical implementation model. I was talking only about the first one. Cenceptually there is only a concept of "visit" and the "visit history" is just a collection of many instances of old "visits". On the physicall level however, you can decide to denormalize the domain and optimize the DB for performance, therefore splitting this concept in two DB tables - e.g. "Visit" to hold the current visits (or last 10 for example) and "VisitHistory" to hold old visits.

Comment: I understand that there are 2 concepts . As my question stated, should the logic that's using the history of persisted objects be inside the domain or outside the domain? For example the uniqueness of an aggregate should outside the domain in a command object (cqrs) . This uniqueness is tied to the history of all persisted aggregates. I will give more thought on this blacklist case . Thanks for you answer. +1 and accepted .

Comment: I see this logic also spread over both models. In Domain model you define implementation-independent part (e.g. functional algorithms, business rules, etc). Please consult my suggested solution, as it describes which parts of logic should (in my opinion) reside in Domain Model. In the implementation model you map them to your concrete solution: persistence, IDs, DB, etc. arise here. StoreVisit therefore maps in two Tables. The method assesLimits() could be implemented in a stored procedure od a Java class or elsewhere, but the implementation-agnostic algorhitm is specified in Domain.